# ggplot multiple lines colored as gradient

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm currently struggling to wrap my head around the following objective:

- a 2x2 facet grid
- in each facet a couple of lines
- each line colored according to some continuous variable

I not even get the simple example working. So far I have:

```
df <- data.frame(xval = rep(1:5, 8),
                 yval = runif(40),
                 pval = rep(c(rep(1,5), rep(2, 5)),4),
                 plt = rep(c(rep("mag", 10), rep("ph", 10)), 2),
                 p = c(rep("p1", 20), rep("p2", 20))
                 )
ggplot(df, aes(xval, yval)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = pval)) +
  facet_grid(plt~p)
```

Would very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Since `pval` is not a factor variable you need to specify the grouping explicitly.

```
ggplot(df, aes(xval, yval)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = pval, group = pval)) +
  facet_grid(plt~p)
```

Comment: That easy. Thanks!

Comment: @Pascal However, usually this is a sign that your plot does not conform to the Grammar of Graphics. You should carefully consider if your approach is advisable.

Comment: By that you mean, that the data.frame should be structured differently? Especially with that I had my problems. Could you suggest a better structure?

Comment: No, by that I mean that your desired plot probably doesn't adhere to what Hadley (and other experts on data visualization) consider principles of a good plot.

Comment: Oh really, why? And how would you visualize it according to the Grammar of Graphics?

Comment: It's unclear what you would like to visualize. What do you want to illustrate/emphasize in your plot?